# Displaying [1-3519:3,3518:3,3517:3,3516:3,3520:3] in log using array list in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I am developing an online examination app,where i have different sections like aptitude, reasoning, verbal reasoning etc.Each section contains questions and radio buttons for answers.I am using Array list for displaying the  questions and options to the student.

```
   My code is as follows:

   if(count==0)
   {
   ArrayList param = new ArrayList();
   param.add(secid);
   param.add(Questionid);
   param.add(answer);
   }
   else
 {
   ArrayList param = new ArrayList();
   param.add(Questionid);
   param.add(answer);
  }
```

I am getting the array list in the following format

[1, 3519, 3, 3518, 3, 3517, 3, 3516, 3, 3520, 3]
where 1 is section id should be displayed at a time.
3519 is question id.
3 is answer.
the loop iterates until condition fails.

But the requirement is [1-3519:3,3518:3,3517:3,3516:3,3520:3] .Is it possible to display a list like this.I didn't have idea please suggest me

Comment: Create pojo class of three strings and create arrayList of that kind of class.

Comment: do you have any design .

Comment: please make a pojo for QuestionModelPojo. this will contain secid, questionId, answer. will make your work easier.

Comment: i have to send array list  which is like[1-3519:3,3518:3,3517:3,3516:3,3520:3] to server

Comment: what is QuestionModelPojo? i didn't have idea

Comment: create a model class , and use array of that class. He meant to create a model class for questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier for you, if u create pojo class. Since your question is to display the array in that particular format I guess this will help.

```
ArrayList<String> param = new ArrayList(); 
if(count==0)
{
param.add(String.valueOf(secid)+ "-" +String.valueOf(Questionid)+":"+String.valueOf(answer);
}
else
{
 param.add(String.valueOf(Questionid)+":"+String.valueOf(answer);
}
```

You can create a string array and make it into a format of your choice.

Comment: [3-3539:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton{f507bdc VFED..C.. ........ 0,64-123,128 #7f0f0087 app:id/option2}, 3536:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton{75779c8 VFED..C.. ........ 0,192-123,256 #7f0f0089 app:id/option4}] .i have worked with your code .

Answer (score 0):

For example :

Model(POJO) Class :

```
public class Notification {

private String msg,date;

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Notification(String msg, String date) {
    this.msg = msg;
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

Create arryList of that class :

private ArrayList arrayList = new new ArrayList<>();

arrayList.add(new Notification("question","post_date"));